# Access Gnosis Safe on forked mainnet

Tags: gnosis-safe

Suppose I run my own stateful fork of ethereum which copies all safes - including my own - over to the new chain.

How could I connect to my copied Safe on the new chain and transfer coins out of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the safe-cli package](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-cli) to interact with Safe contracts on any network

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the comment from @mikheevm:

There are multiple tools that you can use. The following tools are available

- [Safe Python CLI](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-cli)
- [Safe Hardhat CLI](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-tasks)
- [Safe Core SDK](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk) which can be used with scripts to build your own access layer